# How to use QSignalMapper for a list of QAction items

Tags: qt5, signals-slots, qt-signals, qmenu, qaction

I am developing a code snippet to perform similar, not identical actions when I click on the sub menu item list. Please check the attached snapshot. QSignalMapper is the best solution to connect multiple signals to the same slot.

[image: I want to perform similar actions whenever the values in the Area Threshold sub menu are clicked]

But I am not able to exactly place, which signal is to be called for which slot. I have read a lot of theory about QSignalMapper,

```
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html#thesignalmapperapproach
```

even implemented their codes.
Unlike the mentioned sample programs, my QAction objects apparently cannot be defined like we define elements inside an array, coz their names were auto-generated by the design window. 
[image: Names of qAction objects cannot be placed in for loop as they aren't sequential per se]

I am not able to understand, what should I place as SIGNAL here, and when should I use the setMapping function? If I use setMapping function, which parameters should I implement? 
I am simply not getting the concept thorough, not knowing what to do, whom to ask and making the mistake in my code here. Can you please advise me what I am doing wrong?
I checked this for reference coz he had similar issue:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151443/how-to-pass-a-qstring-to-a-qt-slot-from-a-qmenu-via-qsignalmapper-or-otherwise/14157471#14157471
```

***********************************UPDATED SECTION(as of Mar 3, '14)************************************************************************

My problem is quite similar to following question:
    [How to add a list of QActions to a QMenu and handle them with a single slot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187538/qt-how-to-add-a-list-of-qactions-to-qmenu-and-handle-them-with-a-single-slot)

I too, tried using setData in `helpAction(QAction *pAction)`, but I am still mistaken since the only value that I get when I click on the action items in the area threshold sub menu is

```
0
```

So my updated question is, how to use the `setData(const QVariant &userData)` to assign indices to my action items. Please advise.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSignalMapper>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void subMenuForThresholds();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    void createActions();
    QSignalMapper *pSignalMapper;

private slots:
    void interval();
    void help();
    void helpAction(QAction *pAction);
    void setAreathreshold(int value);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "intervaldialog.h"
#include "help.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    createActions();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    ui->actionInterval->setStatusTip(tr("Set the interval for capturing delta & reference images"));
    connect(ui->actionInterval, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(interval()));

    subMenuForThresholds();

    ui->menuHelp->setStatusTip(tr("help "));
//    connect(ui->menuHelp, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(help()));
}

void MainWindow::subMenuForThresholds()
{
    pSignalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
//    connect(pSignalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SIGNAL(/*not sure what to place here?*/);


    connect(ui->menuArea_Threshold, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(helpAction(QAction*)));

}

void MainWindow::setAreaThreshold()
{
   qDebug()<<value;
}


void MainWindow::interval()
{
    qDebug()<<"inside interval qdialog";

    Help help;
    help.exec();
}

void MainWindow::help()
{
    qDebug()<<"inside help qdialog";
    Help help;
    help.exec();
}

void MainWindow::helpAction(QAction *pAction)
{
    ui->action25_sec->setData(10);
    int value = pAction->data().toInt();
    qDebug()<<value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me out.

```
QSignalMapper *pSignalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(pSignalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), SLOT(setAreaThreshold(int)));
connect(ui->action25_s,  SIGNAL(triggered()), pSignalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(ui->action50_sec,  SIGNAL(triggered()), pSignalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(ui->action100_sec, SIGNAL(triggered()), pSignalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(ui->action150_sec, SIGNAL(triggered()), pSignalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(ui->action200_sec, SIGNAL(triggered()), pSignalMapper, SLOT(map()));
pSignalMapper->setMapping(ui->action25_s,   25);
pSignalMapper->setMapping(ui->action50_sec,   50);
pSignalMapper->setMapping(ui->action100_sec, 100);
pSignalMapper->setMapping(ui->action150_sec, 150);
pSignalMapper->setMapping(ui->action200_sec, 200);

// and a slot
void setAreaThreshold(int value) {
 qDebug()<<value;
}
```