# Qt: Context menu / connect with parameters

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I have a problem connecting context menu actions in Qt. I know there are plenty of similar questions around, nevertheless I couldn't find a solution yet.

I have a series of plots built using QCustomplot.

What I want to do is to create a context menu when right-clicking on the background of each plot listing all the signal present in the graph. By clicking an entry of this menu, the corresponding signal should be hidden (if currently visible) or made visible (if hidden).

Now, I've defined a class called PlotHandler of which I paste the relevant parts here below:

**plotHandler.cpp**

```
#include "plothandler.h"

PlotHandler::PlotHandler(QStringList groupNames, int startIdx, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent), scrolling(false), refreshing(true)
{
    pPlot = new QCustomPlot(this);
    pPlot->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(pPlot, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(contextMenuRequest(QPoint)));
}

void PlotHandler::contextMenuRequest(QPoint pos)
{
    int i;
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu(this);
    for(i=0; i<pGroup->getDataLength(); i++)
        {
            QAction *menuEntry;
            menuEntry = new QAction(pPlot->graph(i)->name(), this);
            menuEntry->setProperty("graphIdx", i);
            menu->addAction(menuEntry);
            connect(menuEntry, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(addRemoveGraph()));
        }
        menu->popup(pPlot->mapToGlobal(pos));    
}

void PlotHandler::addRemoveGraph()
{
    QAction *selectedSignal = qobject_cast<QAction *>(sender());
    int tmp = selectedSignal->property("graphIdx").toInt();

    if (pPlot->graph(tmp)->visible())
    {
        pPlot->graph(tmp)->setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        pPlot->graph(tmp)->setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**plotHandler.h**

```
class PlotHandler : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PlotHandler(QStringList groupNames, int startIdx, QWidget *parent = 0);
    QString groupRequested();

private:
    QCustomPlot *pPlot;

public slots:
   void contextMenuRequest(QPoint pos);
   void addRemoveGraph();
}
```

The menu is correctly showed with the right entries and when I click on an action `addRemoveGraph` is called. In debug it gives back the following message:

> The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception. Stopped in
>   thread 0 by: Exception at 0x5d6c2f9a, code: 0xc0000005: read access
>   violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0.

trying to execute

```
int tmp = selectedSignal->property("graphIdx").toInt();
```

Could anyone point me towards the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `menu->exec( QCursor::pos() );` instead of `popup`?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestion. I tried but nothing changed.

Comment: Is `addRemoveGraph()` executed when you select a menu item? Did you try without your `setProperty`?

Comment: Define `nothing happens`. Menu showed? Action selected? `addRemoveGraph` called?

Comment: Edited the question trying to be more specific

Comment: Is `selectedSignal` equal `0x0`?

Comment: Finally I found a solution following the suggestion from Никола Якушев and the slightly different approach described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187538/how-to-add-a-list-of-qactions-to-a-qmenu-and-handle-them-with-a-single-slot). Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `QObject::setProperty` but `QAction` doesn't have a property named "graphIdx". When you attempt to read the "graphIdx" property from `QAction` you will always get an invalid `QVariant`.

```
int tmp = selectedSignal->property("graphIdx").toInt();
// tmp always is 0;
```

You can use `QAction::setData` if you need to store only one property. Otherwise, use `QObject::setProperty` to set a custom property on any `QObject`. `QAction` is a `QObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Here below the solution that solved the issue.

**plotHandler.cpp**

```
#include "plothandler.h"

PlotHandler::PlotHandler(QStringList groupNames, int startIdx, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent), scrolling(false), refreshing(true)
{
    pPlot = new QCustomPlot(this);
    pPlot->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(pPlot, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(contextMenuRequest(QPoint)));
}

void PlotHandler::contextMenuRequest(QPoint pos)
{
    int i;
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu(this);
    for(i=0; i<pGroup->getDataLength(); i++)
        {
            QAction *menuEntry;
            menuEntry = new QAction(pPlot->graph(i)->name(), this);
            menuEntry->setData(i);
            menu->addAction(menuEntry);
        }

    connect(menu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(addRemoveGraph(QAction*)));    
    menu->popup(pPlot->mapToGlobal(pos));    
}

void PlotHandler::addRemoveGraph(QAction *selectedSignal)
{

    int tmp = selectedSignal->property("graphIdx").toInt();

    if (pPlot->graph(tmp)->visible())
    {
        pPlot->graph(tmp)->setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        pPlot->graph(tmp)->setVisible(true);
    }
    pPlot->replot();
}
```

**plotHandler.h**

```
class PlotHandler : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PlotHandler(QStringList groupNames, int startIdx, QWidget *parent = 0);
    QString groupRequested();

private:
    QCustomPlot *pPlot;

public slots:
   void contextMenuRequest(QPoint pos);
   void addRemoveGraph();
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help.